# Must one give up his life in order to avoid performing an abortion?

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, murder, martyr, abortion

According to Halacha, abortion is forbidden, but not punishable by death like a full fledged murder, so would one still be obligated to give up his life in order to avoid doing it, or do we say that your blood is “reder” in this case?

Comment: We say that when the mother's life is threatened.

Comment: @shmosel, that’s because the fetus is directly considered a Rodef in that case

Comment: I don't know how literal that is. Wouldn't you normally require intent to classify a threat as a rodef?

Comment: @shmosel, even if it isn’t literal, it still might not be the same as the case in the question

Comment: Maybe not. It was just a comment.

Comment: Counterpoint: some say you can't even steal to save your own life.

Comment: R' Asher Weiss explains (and he said this pshat got him a yasher koach from ... R' Elyashiv IIRC) that there are two degrees of rodef: to allow what would otherwise be full-blown retzicha, it requires the pursuer's to be knowingly, actively threatening someone. But to destroy property, or prevent a potential life from coming to fruition, there is a lesser standard of rodef that doesn't. (Essentially, then, there is no machlokes between Rashi and Rambam.) This is his opinion, not Rav Moshe Feinstein's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rama [YD 157:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.157.1?lang=he) says that Yeharog Val yaavor applies even if it’s just a lav without the punishment of death:

> וכל איסור עבודת כוכבים וג"ע וש"ד אע"פ שאין בו מיתה רק לאו בעלמא צריך ליהרג ולא לעבור

R’ Moshe understands abortion to be included in the prohibition of murder ([CM 2:69](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&st=&pgnum=291)) so seemingly one would have to give up their life for it. However, many others hold that abortion is other prohibitions but not murder (Maharit, Chavos Yair) in which case one would not have to give up their life for it.

Comment: Generally they say chavalah; R' Asher Weiss holds it's that we would like a potential life to become a full one, in the spirit of *chalel alav shabbos achas* ... -- which sounds more like an *asei*.